# In-App "send feedback mail" button

Tags: ios, app-store, feedback, review

are you allowed to place a "send feedback" button (which would, for instance, open up a mail to app support) in your iOS app?

I recall reading on one of the App Store submission procedure docs and / or UI guidelines that you're not allowed to place a custom "send feedback" form (or button?) in your own app as users should be using the App Store review mechanism instead. However, I can't seem to find this anymore, so I'm not sure if this is still valid.

Does anybody know more about this? It seems an obvious way to (hopefully) get users (even dissatisfied ones) to cooperate with you and prevent them from writing angry reviews without you being able to reply at all.

Comment: Can you provide the exact source where you found this restriction? I never heard/read of that.

Comment: As I said, I can't seem to find the source anymore. Also, this question is pretty old by now and resolved as well, so I'm not sure how I can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have included a "Send Feedback" button in a few apps in the past that opened the email modal without any review issues to date.

Comment: I can confirm that. I have included a "Send Feedback" buttons in all my apps too without any review issues yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not prohibited and in fact, is a MUCH better way to engage with your app customers. My company, Apptentive, provides services to app developers like you to power in-app feedback (an improvement on email because it keeps your customers in the app) and the result of engaging with your customers in the app is that you have far more happy customers and better ratings.